# clang++ error on standard library depending on -std=c++2b version and warning when using -g flag

Tags: linux, clang++

While compilation with g++ works correctly
if I compile with clang++ the command bellow compiles correctly

```
clang++ -std=gnu++20 -c 03_vect.cpp -o Debug/03_vect.cpp.o
```

while the command bellow

```
clang++ -std=gnu++2b -c 03_vect.cpp -o Debug/03_vect.cpp.o;ls -l Debug/03_vect.cpp.o
```

gives

```
In file included from 03_vect.cpp:1:
In file included from ./00_usefull_macros.h:13:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/iostream:41:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/ostream:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/ios:44:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/bits/ios_base.h:41:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/bits/locale_classes.h:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/string:48:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/bits/stl_iterator.h:2618:35: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'iterator_traits<_It>::iterator_category'
      { using iterator_category = iterator_traits<_It>::iterator_category; };
```

Moreover if I compile with the flag -g it gives warning:

03_vect.s:8:2: warning: inconsistent use of MD5 checksums
.file   1 "03_vect.cpp"

Any experience on the above ?

Comment: Not sure how it can give you this warning if it never produces the .s file.

Comment: you are right, the options contained --save-temps and I didn't indicated it.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need clang-16. Earlier versions do not implement [P0634R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html). `libstdc++` uses this feature in the c++2b mode.